# Aframe: How to set an entity class with js?

Tags: aframe

i'm adding aframe entities programmatically.

I didn't find how to set their class so that they get raycaster events.

i tried this without succes:

this.el.setAttribute('class', 'link');

or:

this.el.className = "link";

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (I'm linking MDN, for this is not `aframe` exclusive):

Add a class using

```
this.el.classList.add("myClass");
```

Remove it using

```
this.el.classList.remove("myClass");
```

---

You can check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3uq1rtgd/) fiddle where i add/remove classes to set which objects are clickable. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8f42kpsv/) with a mouse-cursor instead of the classic one.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, the raycaster still doesn't see my entity. perhaps because the entity is created programmatically ? let entity = document.createElement('a-entity'); 
      this.entity.classList.add('link');

Comment: @SWAppDev is it working in my two examples for you ? can you provide an example where you do things "your way", where it doesn't work ?

Comment: @SWAppDev if you create an entity like this: `let entity = document(..)` then you need to change its properties using `entity.classList` not `this.entity.classlist`. Or do you have a `this.entity = entity` somewhere ?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwp16avg/) you have a programmatically created object + added class